# Android maps v2 - get map zoom

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to get the android map to zoom on my marker & leave the marker in the center of the screen.

```
public void onNewLocation(Location location, String name) {
    if (marker == null){
        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
        location.getLatitude(), 
        location.getLongitude()))
        .title(preferencesUtils.getName(getApplicationContext(), preName, key));    
    }
    map.clear();
    marker.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    map.addMarker(marker);                  
}
```

this is the code - what should i add to zoom my marker

Answer (score 2):

To simply zoom in, use:

```
float zoomLevel = 20.0f;
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
```

To zoom to the marker, use:

```
LatLng l = new LatLng(LATPOSITION, LONGPOSITION);
float zoomLevel = 20.0f;
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l, zoomLevel));
```

Add these where you want the zoom to happen.