# Centering google map based on user's geolocation

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have a google map (v2) on my website which i use to get user's latitude and longitude to send them as a form. What i need is to make this map initially be centered based on user's geolocation. I understand it's not a practical question but i'm not very familiar with google maps api and all the tutorial's on web are based on google map v3 and i don't want the hassle to migrate to v3 and write all the stuff all over again. So i appreciate it if someone lead me in the right direction to get this feature working on gmap(v2). Here's how my code looks like:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

    var center = new GLatLng(43.65323, -79.38318);

    map.setCenter(center, 15);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    }

    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    var marker = new GMarker(center, {
        draggable: true
    });
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    document.getElementById("b-lat").value = center.lat().toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("b-longt").value = center.lng().toFixed(5);

    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        var point = marker.getPoint();
        map.panTo(point);
        document.getElementById("b-lat").value = point.lat().toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("b-longt").value = point.lng().toFixed(5);

    });
    GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function () {
        map.clearOverlays();
        var center = map.getCenter();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, {
            draggable: true
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        document.getElementById("b-lat").value = center.lat().toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("b-longt").value = center.lng().toFixed(5);


        GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
            var point = marker.getPoint();
            map.panTo(point);
            document.getElementById("b-lat").value = point.lat().toFixed(5);
            document.getElementById("b-longt").value = point.lng().toFixed(5);

        });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution through `navigator` object. after initializing the map i found the user's lat&longt with this block of code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
        center = new GLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        addMapMarker();
    });
    if(typeof userLatitude == 'undefined' && typeof userLongitude == 'undefined') {
        center = new GLatLng(43.65323, -79.38318);
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        addMapMarker();
    }
} else {
    center = new GLatLng(43.65323, -79.38318);
    map.setCenter(center, 15);
    addMapMarker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my other post: [Android maps v2 - get map zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803568/android-maps-v2-get-map-zoom/20803656#20803656)

To simply zoom in, use:

```
float zoomLevel = 20.0f;
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
```

To zoom to the marker, use:

```
LatLng l = new LatLng(LATPOSITION, LONGPOSITION); float zoomLevel =
20.0f; map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l, zoomLevel));
```

Add these where you want the zoom to happen.

Note: This is for Java android, you *may* need to edit it for the web.